# Masking download link from another server which contains authentication value to the server

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to mask a download link that contains a domain of other server and some authentication value. Problem is whenever the load the download.php page, it will download an unknown file with all the authentication value in the unknown file name. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Below are the authentication code and link to the server.

```
 $sharedSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
    $transactionId = "test001"; 
    $resourceId = "urn:uuid:xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"; 
    $linkURL = "http://acs4.editionguard.com/fulfillment/URLLink.acsm"; 
    $orderSource = "xxxxxx@example.com";

    // Create download URL
    $URL = "action=enterorder&ordersource=".urlencode($orderSource)."&orderid=".urlencode($transactionId)."&resid=".urlencode("$resourceId")."&dateval=".urlencode($dateval)."&gblver=4";

    // Digitally sign the request
    $URL = $linkURL."?".$URL."&auth=".hash_hmac("sha1", $URL, base64_decode($sharedSecret));
```

And below is the php code that I use to generate the download.

```
<?php
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"". $URL ."\"");
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($URL)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($URL).'"');
readfile($URL);
?>
```

Comment: check if `allow_fopen_url` is set, also this code is inefficent because your calling the URL twice, once with filesize and once with readfile

Comment: why are you not following the process set out by the editionguard api? all your doing is increasing your bandwidth useagae.

Comment: @Dagon Problem is I wanted to implement the download in a automated html email. Html email can't read php code, so that I have to implement this download link in my server.

Comment: the api returns a url you can put in to an email

Comment: @Dagon Sorry to ask, I'm still an amateur programmer. How do I pass the PHP $URL variable to the HTML mail body?

Comment: something like : `... $body="here is the book link <a href='".$url."'">click me to download</a>"; ...`

Comment: @Dagon The reason I wanna to put the link and redirect it to my server is because I wanna hide the editionguard URL/path.